# How frequently does recombination occur, and how long are the recombinated fragments?

Tags: genetics, chromosome, meiosis, recombination

I understand the mechanics of recombination, but am struggling with the 'scale'.

1. When two homologous chromosomes pair, roughly how many recombination events occur on average? I understand there will be a distribution, and it will vary between species - but are we talking one, two, or hundreds/thousands?
2. How are long are recombination fragments relative to the entire length of the chromosome? With the same caveat as above, I'm trying to get a sense of scale - 0.001%, 1%, 10%, 25%?

Answer (score 2):

When [crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosomal_crossover) happens, it's a whole swap from that point on, not just a little chunk. So if there's only one crossover event, then the lengths are "p" and "100% - p", where p is the position along the chromosome. The only way to get a small piece of one chromosome amidst a mostly intact copy of the other would be for there to be two crossovers close to each other.

This existing Q&A talks about the rate of crossovers in human chromosomes:

[How many recombination events are there per generation in humans?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19005/how-many-recombination-events-are-there-per-generation-in-humans)

It varies by which chromosome you're talking about and other factors, but something along the order of 1 to 4 events per chromosome would be a reasonable ballpark. 0 is possible, too.